# How to use only one select statment for getting multiple values and add them in array

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm wondering how can I use only a single select mysql statment for getting multiple values from different columns and those values to be added into a array of strings.

For example:

```
string[] Person = new string[3];
"Select Name,Nickname,Age From TableName";
Person[0] = Name
Person[1] = Nickname
Person[2] = Age
```

How can I do that?

What have I tried:

```
 string[] Persons = new string[3];
            command.CommandText = "Select Name From TableName";
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = commmand.ExecuteReader();

            int i = 0;

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    Persons[i] = myReader.GetString(0);
                    i++;
                }
```

I know how to get only for 1 column.

Comment: Um, what data access method are you using? ADO.NET?

Comment: Yes I'm using ado.net . what have I tried ? question updated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `while` loop with:

```
if (myReader.Read())
{
    Persons[0] = myReader.GetString(0);
    Persons[1] = myReader.GetString(1);
    Persons[2] = myReader.GetString(2);
}
myReader.Close();
```

This only reads one row of data. If you need to read more rows, use a loop again. See [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx).